# Странная метка [qregexp]

Tags: поддержка, метки

В свежем вопросе наткнулся на метку [qregexp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qregexp). Судя по первым вопросам и беглому гуглингу, имеется в виду класс [QRegExp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregexp.html) из Qt, но, видимо, пользователи стали лепить её на всё подряд — и на python, и на javascript, и на nginx в вопросы, связанные с регулярками.

Возможно, надо с ней что-нибудь сделать? Убрать из не-Qt вопросов? Или полностью выпилить за ненадобностью?

Comment: может проще ее синонимизировать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @aepot может, но если создатель метки имел в виду конкретно класс из Qt, то получится немножко ой

Comment: 36 вопросов? Почистить всё, что не про класс, да и всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вручную чистить долго и скучно, автоматизировать бы как нибудь...